# Select Window=Null equivalent in webdriver/java

Tags: selenium, selenium2, selenium-ide

While clicking the drop down, Selenium IDE records a selectWindow command as `SelectWindow=null`. What is the equivalent code in webdriver/java ? I tried `driver.switchto.window("null");` but on trying it I get "no such window" exception.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned "the" dropdown, without much details, I can not tell what happens exactly.

- Does a window pop out?
- Does an alert pop out?
- Does a dropdown list expand?

What you can do is to:

1. Before you click this button, execute something like `String Parent_Window = driver.getWindowHandle();` this way, you can store your parent window handle in a string for later use.
2. Click this button.
3. Execute `driver.getWindowHandles()`, this way, you will get a list of all active window handles.
4. Go through this window handle list, do what you want to do.

Without much further details, this is as much as I can help.